# Using Facebook, Twitter, Google conversion pixels when linking to external site

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter

I'm working on a site where conversions involve sending users to Eventbrite pages, where the users can make a purchase. I am using Facebook, Twitter, and Google ads, but they seem to require my site having a second page with a conversion pixel to track conversions. Since my homepage is sending the user to Eventbrite, where I can't add the pixel since I cannot adjust the pages' code, I am having a hard time figuring out the best way to use a pixel to track conversions. Any help with how to do this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote to [Eventbrite](https://www.eventbrite.com.au/) to ask them this very question, and got the unhappy answer:

> "Unfortunately, we currently are not offering the ability to use
>   conversion pixels on event pages.  The closest thing we have would be
>   using Google Analytics on your event pages."

As I use infusionsoft, I am looking into replacing Eventbrite with a plugin like: http://marketplace.infusionsoft.com/app/dynamicsync which has the App for attendance, the Wordpress plugin for sales, and automatically connects to my CRM, so I don't need to create Zapier Zap for every event I create.

Considering I pay Eventbrite an average of $100 per event in fees, I think the $20 per month is worth it for this type of software, that means I can control the HTML on the pages, and keep people inside my website.  I might just have to get HTTPS certs' on my website, or add online purchasing to my system, which apparently Infusionsoft can do, just haven't harnessed that yet.

Answer (score 0):

EventBrite has since added Pixel ID's for Twitter, Adwords and Google Analytics.You can go to 'Manage Event' and scroll down to Tracking Pixel under Analyze.

Unfortunately they don't provide a Facebook Tracking Pixel support by default. The closest thing I have come to is using the Order Confirmation page to insert the pixel JS.